# Hive json data from one table to another

Tags: json, hive, load

I have a table A in Hive with one column a1 that contains json.

```
Table A
   Columns - a1
```

The json in column a1 has 5 attributes (j1,j2,j3,j4,j5), for example.

I need to load data from table A to another table B.

```
Table B
       Columns - b1, b2, b3, b4, b5
```

The rule to load data from A to B is as follows,

```
b1 - j1
b2 - j2
b3 - j3
b4 - a1 (entire column of A)
```

How can this be done?

And there might be a need to load data from B to another table C.

```
Today C 
  Columns - c1, c2, c3
```

c1, c2, c3 are loaded with data from columns b1,b2,b3 of B

```
c1 - b1
c2 - b2
c3 - b3
```

But it might be required to add another column c4 to C and c4 would have to be loaded with one of the json attributes (j4) from column b4 of B.

```
c1 - b1
c2 - b2
c3 - b3
c4 - one of the json attributes from column b4 of B
```

Is this possible? If so, can you please give me some pointers?

Any other solution is also fine. All i want is to store the JSON in the history so that its attributes can be retrieved later. In the example above, table A is a staging table and so temporary.

Answer (score 0):

Hive has a UDF called `get_json_object`.

It can use the json path of

- $ : Root object
- . : Child operator
- [] : Subscript operator for array
- *: Wildcard for []

Comment: In terms of performance, is it a good choice to have the JSON itself as one of the columns in B and then use UDF to load into C or have the JSON in another table D with D created with JSON-serde, then join B, D to load into C?

Comment: @ManikandanKannan I guess use a JSON serde table is better than call the UDF, but the join afterwards will cost you a lot of time.So if the UDF way can avoid the join,use the UDF is better.